# Extracing numbers in different formats from cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract numbers from cells that contains text and numbers in Google Sheets. However, the format of the numbers is inconsistent. Thousands separator and decimal separator are not used consistently.I have some mock data below:

Column A
in the amount of $1910.06 on
una transferencia de 15,01 EUR a la
received 650,40 € on
in the amount of 1.009,62 EUR
montant de € 16.19 vers
in the amount of 99.77 PLN
in the amount of CDN$ 1209.23

I am looking for the following output in column B:
Column B
1910.06
15.01
650.04
1009.62
16.19
99.77
1209.23

I was trying to work with REGEXEXTRACT but don't know what the correct parameters are to make this work.
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[A-Za-z]+", ""), "[!@#$%€^&*()]", ""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7&"", ",", "."), "\d+(?:.\d+)?")*1)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10&"", "\d+\.\d{3}"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10, ".", ), A1:A10), ",", ".")&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?")*1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything worked fine except in row 4, the 62 Eurocents are not added to column B. It would have been totally fine for my purpose, but then I saw Osm's reply and that answer considers that aspect. Thanks again!

Comment: @sunchips answer updated